# decorating classes with properties to avoid duplication

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to work out the best way to approach the following ..

i need to pass `AvailabilityOption/LimitedAvailabilityOption` types to  - well a service as it happens, and then get back `BookingOption`  types.

I have routines which will generate the availability types, but am unsure if i need to go through each of my `Option` objects effectively duplicating versions of them inheriting from `BookingOption` and `AvailabilityOption` in turn. or can I do some sort of 'Decoration' of the simple options with the availability classes and then cast them back down to booking ones when i pass them back again.
I know there is a decoration pattern but having read a bit about this it appears that it is more about decorating at runtime.. I may well be misunderstanding.
I suspect I havent explained this very well but here is some code..

**EDIT**: *effectively the option is a base for a number of possible options on a booking - such as an excursion or some other extra, of which there are quite afew. the availability extends that to determine what space there is on any option, but it is just extending the option itself, with the price and possibly the numbers already booked on that option.
the `BookingOption` is there to be returned from the routine that effectively chooses from the options based on their price and availability. I am just trying to return the bare minimum at the booking point, which is really the date when the option is required and which option it is. the availability at this point is moot..*

```
public abstract class Option{
    public int OptionID { get; set; }
    public OptionType OptionType { get; set; }
    public string EqtCode { get; set; }
    public string CentreCode { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }     
}

public abstract BookingOption : Option{
    public DateTime WeekStartDate{get;set;}
}

public abstract class AvailabilityOption : BookingOption {
    public decimal Price{get;set;}

    public override string Description{
        get{return string.format("{0} @ {1}", base.Description, Price.ToString());
        set{ base.Description = value;}
    }
}

public abstract class LimitedAvailabilityOption : AvailabilityOption{
    public int MinNumber { get; set; }
    public int MaxNumber { get; set; }
    public int TotalBooked { get; set; }
    public int TotalRemaining { get; set; }
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} ({1} @ {2})",
                base.Description, TotalRemaining.ToString(), Price.ToString());
        }
        set { base.Description = value;}
    }
}

public class Option1 : Option{
    public Option1(){}
}

public class Option2 : Option{
    public Option2(){}
}

public List<BookingOption> BookWithAvail(List<AvailabiliyOption> options){
//pick options based on avail and pass back the booking versions so write away...
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little more info about essence of 'Availability' and 'Option' concepts and about relationships between them - in the business logic of your application? It seems like answer depends on what is the purpose of those classes and concepts behind them.

Comment: @ Andrii amended.. hope that explains it further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like answer depends on how you plan to use *Availability* and *Limited availabilitty* qualities of essences. If those *availability*-qualities are only applicable to `LimitedAvailabilityOption` and `AvailabilityOption` classes - than it does not seems there is a big need of implementation `Availability` or `LimitedAvailability` in separate classes, as each of those classes will be used to distinguish only one kind of other essences (`LimitedAvailabilityOption` and `AvailabilityOption` respectively). It would make sense to use decoration pattern and implement classes for *Availability* and *Limited availability* qualities only if you plan assign each of them to multiple essences that are not connected with inheritance relationship (including inheritance through intermediate classes). And if you plan to spread usage of *availability*-qualities across multiple classes that are not supposed to have any inheritance connection via common ancestor that has *availability* property - then the only choice is to extract those *availability* qualities into separate classes.